# JAAS - user groups (from kerberos)

Tags: java, jaas

In general how are user groups retrieved in JAAS?

It appears to me that each request generates a javax.security.auth.Subject and somehow the Groups are mapped to javax.security.auth.Principal?

In addition how does a Kerberos implementation get the list of groups from a token?

Comment: Kerberos deals with *authentication* - why should it care for Groups, which are typically used for *authorization*?? That's the job for an LDAP directory. (sigh) OK, Microsoft Active Directory does some very ugly things to stuff Group information inside the Kerberos TGT, but that's a **perversion**. And it's a custom implementation.

Comment: Hi Samson. I think the answer to my question is to perform a Ldap / AD group lookup once I am authenticated.

Comment: Hello IanWaston, did you figure out how to do authorization using jaas +Kerberos? I am having this issue as well. Thanks